# Cannot convert poorly formed answer into comment

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, moderator-tools, convert-to-comment

I'm trying to convert an answer into a comment, but the system keeps rejecting my conversion with an irrelevant reason:

[image]

Well, I guess the message is *true*, but not particularly relevant in this situation

Comment: There's a really easy interim solution: edit the answer to remove one of the @-signs.

Comment: @Emrakul yes, this is what I did

Comment: Wow, so this has been around since 2011! How did I not run into this before now?!

Comment: @Mark it's quite rare to have pings like that in posts. :)

Comment: Incidentally, if "convert to comment" doesn't work perfectly you should probably ask yourself if it's really a good comment. In particular, very long "comments" and comments that respond to multiple answers might be better off left as answers... or just deleted. As Emrakul notes, you can work around this if necessary (I've once or twice converted the same answer to comments multiple times, editing in between) - but consider that akin to making furniture with an axe.